# will there be a degradation in performance if i install 2 OS?

Tags: windows-7, performance, operating-systems, fedora

I was planning 2 OS systems on my laptop. One is already installed which is Win7 and second one that i need to install is fedora. Is it that if i install fedora there will be a degradation in the performance when i work with windows 7 and even fedora ? I won't install fedora in the virtual machine but by partitioning the hard drive.

I have 4GB RAM and a 32 bit processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean dual booting Fedora and Windows they will operate entirely independently of each other and so will have no performance affect on each other.

You will have a menu at boot to select which one to use.

Lots of useful info here:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/06/27/how-to-dual-boot-fedora-15-and-windows-7/